# Jasmine spyOn lodash method 'set'

Tags: angular, jasmine, lodash

I am using `set` in my code. It is used as such

```
import * as set from 'lodash/set';

................

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  redirectWithHref$: Observable<void> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ActionWithPayload>(REDIRECT_TO_EXTERNAL),
    map(action => action.payload),
    tap(url => set(window.location, 'href', url))
  );

................
```

I am trying to `spyOn` with Jasmine, however it has no additional methods, when I attempt to spy it complains that it could not find an object to spy on.

```
 ​​​​AuthEffects redirectWithHref should call set on the window with the payload as the url​​​​ ​​​[74 ms]​​​​
    ​​​​
    ​​Failed: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for default()​​
    ​​Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)​​
      at t.<anonymous> ​src/app/store/auth/auth.effects.spec.ts:111:6​
```

My test looks like....

```
 describe('redirectWithHref', () => {
    fit('should call set on the window with the payload as the url', async(() => {
      const { effects, actions } = setup({});
      const setSpy = spyOn(set, 'default');
      actions.next({ type: REDIRECT_TO_EXTERNAL, payload: 'http://foo.bar' });

      expect(setSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://foo.bar');
    }));
  });
```

How can I spy on this? Using Angular 6 w/ NgRX 6

Comment: `spyOn(set, 'default');` will look for a function named `default` in the object `set` and I think it does not exist, am I right?

Comment: It will, however if you have a default export, such as ```export default class()=> {}``` it will pick up on that I believe.